# How to extract data from xml file containing more than one xml declaration with Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I got a xml file from a online resource, which is the result output of a program called MetaMap mapping biomedical text to concepts in a corpus called UMLS® Metathesaurus. The original xml file is rather complex, so I have just listed a small part of the information. Each `<PMID>` represents one biomedical article
and `<UttText>` store some sentences from that article. `<MMO>`store info for one article.

But As you can see from the file, it has many xml files, each start with
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and only store info for one article -- only one `<MMO>` under `<MMOS>` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE MMOs PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD MetaMap Machine Output//EN"
        "http://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/DTD/MMOtoXML_v5.dtd">

     <MMOs>
      <MMO>

       <PMID>000001</PMID>
       <UttText>abcdefg</UttText>  

      </MMO>
     </MMOs>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE MMOs PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD MetaMap Machine Output//EN" "http://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/DTD/MMOtoXML_v5.dtd">

     <MMOs>
      <MMO>

       <PMID>000002</PMID>
       <UttText>higklm</UttText>  

      </MMO>
     </MMOs>
```

Now I have only tried selecting codes about one record out --named **a1.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE MMOs PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD MetaMap Machine Output//EN"
            "http://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/DTD/MMOtoXML_v5.dtd">

         <MMOs>
          <MMO>

           <PMID>000001</PMID>
           <UttText>abcdefg</UttText>  

          </MMO>
         </MMOs>
```

and do the Xpath query on that using the following java codes:

```
package MBR;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;  
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;  
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;  
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;  
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;  
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;  

import org.w3c.dom.Document;  
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;  

public class MappedMBR {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);  
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
            Document doc = builder.parse("src/a1.xml");  

            XPathFactory pathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance(); 
            XPath xpath = pathFactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression pathExpression = xpath.compile("//PMID/text() | //UttText/text()"); 

            Object result = pathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);  

            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;  
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {  
                    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());  
    }
        }
}
```

So is there any way for XPath to recognise each root element  in one file, or should I delete every other xml declarations and root element `<MMOs>` except the first one in the file?  If so, how to realise it in java?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What you're dealing with is not one XML file, it's several XML files concatenated. Trying to use it like it is one XML file won't work.

Since it is several XML files, your best bet is to **make it** several XML files, rather than keeping it in one.

You could try to do it in a fully compliant way by leveraging XML reader interfaces that would read markup on the go and you write them back to a new file, then detect when the root element closing markup happens, and work on the underlying BufferedReader to advance to the next XML declaration and thus treat the next document the same way.

Or you could load your whole file in memory as String, and split() it by XML declarations. A little less reliable as it's possible to put in an XML document something that's just like an XML declaration, but this is unlikely to happen and this method is much simpler.